# Add rows to complete melted tibble

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tibble

Consider this "melted" tibble:

`structure(list(country = c("Canada", "US", "Canada"), gender = c("male",  "male", "female"), count = c(1, 5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -3L ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

| country | gender | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | male | 1 |
| US | male | 5 |
| Canada | female | 3 |

So Canada has a count for males and a count for females, while the US only has a count for males. This implicitly means that US x female count is zero. Since it's 2 countries times 2 genders, the number of rows should be 4, but the row with zero count is omitted. Is there a way to add a row US-female-0 to "complete" this tibble?

A simple way to do it is to reshape to wide and then to long again:

```
df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = gender, values_from = count) %>% 
    mutate(female = ifelse(is.na(female), 0, female)) %>% 
    reshape2::melt("country") %>% 
    tibble
```

But this is long to write, it may be slow, and is complex if the widened data is bigger than this.

Another possibility, which seems smarter, is:

```
cross_join(df %>% distinct(country), df %>% distinct(gender)) %>%
    left_join(df) %>%
    mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(count), 0, count))
```

But this is not easy to insert in the middle of a pipe, for example in case `df` itself comes from a pipe, without breaking into multiple operations or using global assignment.

Is there a simple way to do this "completion" of the data that is reasonably fast, scalable, and works inside a pipe?

Comment: I would recommend converting your gender column to a factor. While Mael's answer works given your input, if your sample data didn't include any women, or had an 'other' category, then they wouldn't be included as rows in the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
tidyr::complete(df, country, gender, fill = list(count = 0))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  country gender count
  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1 Canada  female     3
2 Canada  male       1
3 US      female     0
4 US      male       5
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. It's the fastest of the solutions here (slightly) and it's the simplest to include in a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code

```r
df %>% right_join(df %>% expand(country,gender), by=join_by(country,gender)) %>% 
  mutate(count=replace_na(count,0))


# A tibble: 4 × 3
  country gender count
  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1 Canada  male       1
2 US      male       5
3 Canada  female     3
4 US      female     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the documentation for `complete()` says *"this is a wrapper around expand(), dplyr::full_join() and replace_na()"*, here's a way using base R:

```
genders <- c("male", "female", "other")

merge(df,
     expand.grid("country" = unique(df$country), "gender" = genders),
     all = TRUE) |>
    transform(count = ifelse(is.na(count), 0, count))
```